# Identify a 90s show about ruthless careerist

Tags: identify-this-tv-show

I saw a show in the 90s about a young man who gets an entry level job (admin or maybe data entry) in a big corporation.
He quickly climbs the corporate ladder by manipulating, backstabbing and blackmailing his colleagues.

At one point the guy drugged this one woman who was trying to expose him by putting something in her glass and accused her of being a drug addict.
The woman denied the charge but to settle the matter, a drug test was ordered, which she failed and was thus fired.

At the end of the season it was suggested that the guy got the entry level position that he was initially in, by killing and impersonating the person who was actually hired for it.

Also, at one point, the camera followed the guy as he was getting back to his expensive apartment in an exclusive high rise (I want to say in NYC) to reveal that the apartment was empty and that he slept in a cardboard box set in one corner of his bedroom.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds like you're looking for [Profit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profit_%28TV_series%29) from 1996.

> Jim Profit is a newly promoted junior-executive at Gracen & Gracen (G&G), a multinational conglomerate that often engages in unethical business practices while actively cultivating a positive public image. G&G’s dark side does not bother Profit, who is not above using blackmail, bribery, extortion, or worse to get ahead himself.

Jim was raised in a cardboard box. And I'm pretty sure that at some point he drugs a co-worker and hypnotizes her so she wouldn't pass a lie detector test (**EDIT:** [It was in episode 4](http://mental-block.wikia.com/wiki/Profit)). The show is often lauded as being ahead of its time, but it was sadly cancelled after a handful of episodes. Here's a clip from the show where Jim sleeps in that cardboard box:

Comment: Wow, that did not take long! Thanks a lot, I was trying to find this show for the longest time.

Comment: No problem! The show is somewhat of a cult favorite.

Comment: I'll definitely re-watch it now that I know what it is called. I can't believe it got canceled after a single season. I was hoping that there were more episodes.

Comment: Sure, I'd say it's worth a re-watch. It kinda beat *House of Cards* to the punch (on *several* counts) 17 years before it.

Comment: @Walt though of course the [original BBC *House of Cards*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_of_Cards_(UK_TV_series)) was 6 years before *this* ahead-of-its-time show, in 1990

Comment: You're right, though I don't think I ever saw it. Was it as dark?